Apache CXF doesn't mask attributes of xml tag while sending request
I'm sending Rest request with xml in it using CXF. I want to hide fields with this code
    Set<String> FIELD_NAMES = new HashSet<String>() {{
        add("fieldToMask");
    }};
    LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
    loggingFeature.addSensitiveElementNames(FIELD_NAMES);

It masks fields like this:
<fieldToMask>XXX</fieldToMask>

But it doesn't mask tag's attribute
<tag1 fieldToMask="value1"></tag1>

I googled how to do it, but found just documentation about addSensitiveElementNames() method. I think, I could do custom logs handling with extending Slf4jEventSender, but is there any simple way that could do what I want?
